Civi Mail - issue adding gmail account: Failed to connect to the server: imap.gmail.com:993
When trying to add a mail account to Civi I get the error message below. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I am trying to connect Civi to my gmail account (which is linked to Civi via 0AUTH).
The port used for the IMAP connection by my server provider is 995, so I won't be able to access it from port 933, as they don't open other ports. Any idea as to how to work around this?
The error message:
"An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: imap.gmail.com:993."
Thank you already in advance!

Are you using POP or IMAP? It sounds like you have a mix of settings. If you're using POP in the protocol field, then the server would be pop.gmail.com. Or if you really want IMAP then you need to change the protocol field to IMAP.

Ah, sorry! I made a mistake when typing the question here. I am using IMAP in the protocol field too.

Ok no problem. But then I'm still a bit confused because nobody uses 995 for IMAP, it's always 993 (or 143). It sounds like you're saying your hosting provider is blocking outbound port 993, but that would be very unusual.
